# What does this mean: "OpenSSL 1.1.0g 2 Nov 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1a 20 Nov 2018)"

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, compilation, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04 which is shipped with OpenSSL 1.1.0g.

I have been trying to link manually compiled python from source to a manually compiled OpenSSL1.1.1a from source. I do not intend to overwrite my system's (Ubuntu) OpenSSL 1.1.0g. However, after my attempts, when I check Ubuntu's OpenSSL using: `openssl version -v`

I get this output:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018)
```

Previously it prints only:
    OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

What does this mean? How can I make my system's OpenSSL 1.1.0g such that my default Python program use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

> export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path"

In-place of "path" provide the location of system's Openssl library.